# 1 Series with multiple not connected lines?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex4.6

- How could be achieved the chart drawn bellow with 1 Chart Series, which can represent multiple not connected, and if possible not sequential ( on the X axis ) lines ?

[image]

Comment: Do you actually ever attempt to do your own work?

Answer (score 1):

```
    var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();   
    drawChart([ [0,50], [70, 100], [120, 190] ], sprite);

    private function drawChart(data:Array, sprite:Sprite):void {

            var grachics:Graphics = sprite.graphics;
            grachics.beginFill(0xffff00);

            for (var i:int = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var obj:Array = data[i] as Array;

                var startX:int = obj[0];
                var endX:int = obj[1];

                grachics.drawRect(startX, 0, endX - startX, 30);
            }

            graphics.endFill();
    }
```